hosting a text file under SharePoint root site
we have our company site hosted under https://www.abc.com.ca
for apple pay verification purpose they wanted a specific file to be hosted under following URL:
https://www.abc.com.ca/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

I tried creating the document library named .well-known, in that case the display name stands as .well-known but when it comes to browsing the text file it omits the . and - on the folder name and gives the URL as below:
https://www.abc.com.ca/wellknown/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

how to retain the folder name as .well-known at the time of browsing as well? the text file needs to be hosted in the above URL.
